# how to change one col value using the information from other cols in the same df

Tags: r

I have a data.farme that looks like this:

[image]

I want to generate a new df as codebook where the numbers in col `Label` will be replaced using the information from `ID` and `Subject`.

what should I do?

The codebook file that I want to achieve is sth that looks like this:

[image]

Sample data can be build using codes:

```
df<-structure(list(Var = c("Subject1", "Subject2", "Subject4", "Subject5", 
"Subject6", "Score1", "Score2", "Score3", "Score4", "Score5", 
"Score6", "TestDate1", "TestDate2", "TestDate3", "TestDate4", 
"TestDate5", "TestDate6"), Label = c("Subject 1", "Subject 2", 
"Subject 4", "Subject 5", "Subject 6", "Score for Subject 1", 
"Score for Subject 2", "Score for Subject 3", "Score for Subject 4", 
"Score for Subject 5", "Score for Subject 6", "Date for test Subject 1", 
"Date for test Subject 2", "Date for test Subject 3", "Date for test Subject 4", 
"Date for test Subject 5", "Date for test Subject 6"), ID = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Subject = c("Math", 
"ELA", "PE", "Art", "Physic", "Chemistry", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_replace_all` with a named vector

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 <- df %>%
   transmute(Var, Label = str_replace_all(Label,
            setNames(na.omit(Subject), na.omit(ID))))
```

-output

```
df1
# A tibble: 17 x 2
#   Var       Label                          
#   <chr>     <chr>                          
# 1 Subject1  Subject Math                   
# 2 Subject2  Subject ELA                    
# 3 Subject4  Subject Art                    
# 4 Subject5  Subject Physic                 
# 5 Subject6  Subject Chemistry              
# 6 Score1    Score for Subject Math         
# 7 Score2    Score for Subject ELA          
# 8 Score3    Score for Subject PE           
# 9 Score4    Score for Subject Art          
#10 Score5    Score for Subject Physic       
#11 Score6    Score for Subject Chemistry    
#12 TestDate1 Date for test Subject Math     
#13 TestDate2 Date for test Subject ELA      
#14 TestDate3 Date for test Subject PE       
#15 TestDate4 Date for test Subject Art      
#16 TestDate5 Date for test Subject Physic   
#17 TestDate6 Date for test Subject Chemistry
```

---

or using `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
df$Label <- with(df, gsubfn("(\\d+)", 
       setNames(as.list(na.omit(Subject)), na.omit(ID)), Label))
```

Comment: Many thanks. Could you help me sort out the thought ? `str_replace_all(Label,
            setNames(na.omit(Subject), na.omit(ID))`. which is `str_replace_all (Label, pattern, replacement)`. So `setNames(na.omit(Subject), na.omit(ID)` is working like a looping?

Comment: @Stataq It is matching the 'ID' element with the value in the Label column and replace that with the 'Subject' value